# Form Submit Redirect Based on Form Data

Tags: php, javascript, forms

Is it possible to redirect someone to a new page based on their input in a form? Basically, on this statistics web app, when someone enters in a username into the search box and hits submit, I'd like them to be sent do domain.com/username_input (Essentially, the form is only being used to allow someone to enter the username, it's not getting sent anywhere).

Not sure if this is possible in HTML+PHP or if it would be best done with JavaScript (that is if it is possible at all)

I feel like javascript redirecting or changing the header location is a bit iffy. In this case, changing the header location wouldn't work anyways.

I tried:

```
<input id="submit" value="Submit" type="submit" onclick="window.location = window.location + '/' + string.value; return false;"/>
```

But I get sent to domain.com/?string=form_input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

javascript with a redirect on the submit button would work.

```
<form name="f" onsubmit="javascript:redirect()">
    First name: <input type="text" name="fname">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

function validateForm()
{
    var x=document.forms["f"]["fname"].value;
    window.location = "http://www.page.com/"+x
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var form = document.redirect; //access the form
document.onsubmit = function(){
    var username = form.username.value; //get username
    form.action = username + "_input";
    return true; // go to page.
};
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TbQWC/2/

​